# Dragging/dropping elements onto designated area then outputting coordinates

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on an AngularJS app which will allow a user to drag HTML elements onto a designated area. I then need to be able to output the coordinates of the elements dropped onto the designated area.

The UI will look something like this:

[image: UI]

So the user drags objects from the panel on the left onto the designated area on the right. They will then be able to set a number of properties for that element as shown in the bottom panel (however this is something I'm confident in doing). What I'm unsure about is how I can create the functionality to allow objects to be dropped at a certain position on the designated area, then have the web app output the coordinates of all the objects.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this functionality?

Comment: Hi, have you resolve your problem now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to [**this url**](http://www.benfarrell.com/2013/03/30/drag-and-drop-with-angularjs-and-jquery-ui/), this is what you need.
After, to get the position, its easy, using angular.element(droppedElement).[**position**](http://api.jquery.com/position)() which return the position from its parent element which is your dropzone.